# How to scan in strings using a loop then storing those words in an array?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main () 
{
 char word[100][21] ;

puts( "Enter Your Words" );

puts( "Enter STOP To Get Your Results" );

   while( strcmp( word, "STOP" ) ) 

   {
    scanf( "%20s", word );

   }

return 0;
}
```

After I scan in a word id like to store it into an array called `storing[][]`, but I dont know how to achieve that, and also I dont want to store the terminating `STOP` word

Comment: Multiple problems in your code. First you're using word before you've given it any value in the `while` loop. Try using `do {} while` loop instead. Also `word` is a multidimensional array. You could do `scanf("%20s", word[0])` for instance but using `word` alone isn't correct.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: consistently indent the code.  Suggest 4 spaces per indent level (never use tabs for indenting). Indent after every opening brace '{'. Unindent before every closing brace '};.

Comment: posted code fails to index through the array `word[]`.  posted code tries to compare contents of `word` with some string that has not yet been input.  Posted code fails to check returned value (not parameter value) from `scanf()` to assure the operation was successful

Comment: Posted code contains 'magic' numbers (100, 21).  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, maintain.  Suggest give the 'magic' numbers meaningful names via `#define` statements and then use those meaningful names throughout the code.

Comment: suggest: scaning into a local char array,  then checking that array for the "stop" string.  If equal to the "stop" string, then exit the input loop, otherwise use strcpy to copy the local char array to the `word[x[` buffer. Then increment `x` in preparation for the next loop.  You might want to make use of the `for()` statement for handling the variable `x`.

Answer (score 1):

Code what you want.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define WORD_MAX 100

int main (void)
{
    char storing[WORD_MAX][21]; /* you want the words stored into storing[][], not word */
    char buffer[21]; /* a buffer to store the word temporaly for not to store STOP to storing */
    int wordCount = 0; /* count how many words are stored */

    puts( "Enter Your Words" );

    puts( "Enter STOP To Get Your Results" );

    /* loop while there is room to store new word left in the array,
     * successfully read something and what is read is not the STOP word */
    while(wordCount < WORD_MAX && scanf("%20s", buffer) == 1 && strcmp(buffer, "STOP") != 0)
    {
        /* store the word read and increment the count */
        strcpy(storing[wordCount++], buffer);
    }

    /* sample code for testing: print what is read */
    {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < wordCount; i++) printf("%03d : %s\n", i, storing[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's the point in adding the braces around `int i;` and the for loop? Seems like clutter to me.

Comment: To create a block to define a variable inside so that the declared variable won't affect another part of the program.

Comment: Suggest `#defined WORD_N 21` or the like.